# const double *bar = (const double *) foo;?

Tags: c, pointers, declaration

I'm working on some C code where a variable declaration is bothering me. Actually the code is working fine but I don't understand it !

I have a variable declaration which is kind of looking that way :

```
    double *foo;
    // Here is the "weird" declaration :
    const double *bar = (const double *) foo;
```

If I think I understand the first half of the declaration and wether the memory address or the actual value is constant (in this case bar is a pointer to const double, correct me if I'm wrong ?), I don't quite understand the `(const double *)`part.

Is this a way of converting the pointer to double foo directly into a const double ?

Anyway, what is the interest of such a declaration ?

Thank You !

Comment: It's a cast and totally unnecessary. `const double *bar = foo;` is sufficient

Comment: https://cdecl.org/ for future reference

Comment: @gst, thank you !! Didn't know this website !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the "second part" as if the pointer foo declared early like

```
double *foo;
```

is redeclared (reinterpreted) like having the type `const double *`

```
const double *bar = (const double *) foo;
```

The casting is not required. You may just write

```
const double *bar = foo;
```

It means that now the value of the pointer bar is the same as the value of the pointer foo. That is the both pointers point to the same object. But know using the pointer bar that points to the same object as the pointer foo you may not change the pointed object.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't it working if you eliminate (const double *)part?

```
double *foo;
// Here is the "weird" declaration :
const double *bar = foo;
```

Should work in the same way